# Is there a way to select a specific type of data using the alpha vantage api? (python, alpha vantage, rapid api, requests)

Tags: python, python-requests, alpha-vantage

Is there any way using the alpha vantage api that I can select the specific type of data such as the days open or close? I've gotten the api to output a global quote for the day, which is a string of everything(open, close, high, low, volume, etc). I just need to grab specific data each time I make a request. I am using request and rapid api along with alpha vantage to get the data.

This is the code that makes a request

```
import requests

url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"

querystring = {"symbol":"TSLA","function":"GLOBAL_QUOTE"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "key"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

This is the basic code that I got from rapid api. The response.text looks like this when outputted

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "TSLA",
        "02. open": "1405.0100",
        "03. high": "1429.5000",
        "04. low": "1336.7100",
        "05. price": "1389.8600",
        "06. volume": "21180300",
        "07. latest trading day": "2020-07-07",
        "08. previous close": "1371.5800",
        "09. change": "18.2800",
        "10. change percent": "1.3328%"
    }
}
```

I've tried cutting the global quote string down using the split function in python but it becomes very finicky. If anyone knows any way to do this, it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by importing Time Series and getting the data out of the pandas dataframe.

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime as dt
import requests

ts = TimeSeries (key=keys, output_format = "pandas")

   ### STOCK TIME SERIES > DAILY ADJUSTED ###
        # Date / Open / High / Low / Close / Adjusted Close / Volume / Dividend / Split
data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=stock_ticker, outputsize ='compact')
        # data_daily['column name'][row number]
data_daily_lastOpenPrice = data_daily['1. open'][0]
data_daily_lastHighPrice = data_daily['2. high'][0]
data_daily_lastLowPrice = data_daily['3. low'][0]
data_daily_lastAdjustedClosingPrice = data_daily['5. adjusted close'][0]
data_daily_lastTradingVolume = data_daily['6. volume'][0]
data_daily_lastDividendAmount = data_daily['7. dividend amount'][0]
```

Hope this information helps :)